# Spring Security logout doesn't logout but correctly redirects to logout-success-url

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I've tried to add Spring Security into my app but I don't seem able to make the log out work.

In my springcontext.xml I have:

```
<logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

and I try to log out using:

```
<p><a href="APP/j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a></p>
```

OR

```
<form action="APP/j_spring_security_logout" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" value="LOG OUT"/>
</form>
```

In both cases I get redirected to `login.xhtml` but when I try to go back to restricted pages that should be filtered I can access it without problem and the user is still logged in.

Comment: Why do you think it's the logout that isn't working? It could be your secured portion of the application is not protected at all.

Comment: @Bart Well the first time I access said page it requires login correctly..

Comment: @KubaSpatny show us the rest of your security context please